# while diploying or building docker image for java application using tomcat:9 i'm facing error that no such directory target/*.war

Tags: java, docker, devops, tomcat9

Dockerfile

```sh
FROM tomcat:9.0

LABEL "project"="java_app"
LABEL "author"="vikas"

# To remove the default ROOT web applications
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT


# To copy war file to the webapps directory in the docker container
COPY target/*.war var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/

# Expose the default tomcat port
EXPOSE 8080

# Start tomcat when the container starts
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

```
 CACHED [2/3] RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT               0.0s
 => ERROR [3/3] COPY target/*.war var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/               0.1s
------
 > [3/3] COPY target/*.war var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/:
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
   9 |
  10 |     # To copy war file to the webapps directory in the docker container
  11 | >>> COPY target/*.war var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/
  12 |
  13 |     # Expose the default tomcat port
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3438055024/target: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have a target directory? did you create it? Normally target is an example we gave you should create an empty directory and place the name of that directory.

Comment: I did not create target directory, but after running mvn package it will create target folder and application packages

Comment: Ok then go this path /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3438055024/ and then use the ls command to verify if it created the target directory. Also, some time last directory is present but some other direct from the path is missing. you need to check if this path has all the directories if not then create them.

Comment: The `target` directory needs to exist on your host before you run `docker build`; did you need to run `mvn package` first?  It could help to [edit] the question and describe the problem in a little more detail, including what command(s) you ran.